# JTable missing .addRow()?

Tags: java, swing, model, jtable, row

I have been wondering why a jTable hasn't got an `.addRow()` method by default. Why do you have to set a `Model` before this is possible?

```
JTable table = new JTable();
table.addRow();
```

The above is not possible, however:

```
JTable table2 = new JTable();
table2.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
table2.addRow(...);
```

After setting the new model, it IS possible - why?

Comment: And what makes you think it is possible ? I do not see an `JTable#addRow` method in the Javadoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, by default, the `TableModel` is not mutable (other then being able to, potentially, modify the existing data), that is, there are no methods within `TableModel` that provide any means to add or delete rows.

It is up to implementations of `TableModel` to decide if that functionality is possible.  Take a look at [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) for details about what the default interface provides

Secondly, it is the responsibility of the model to manage the data. It makes no sense for the table to suddenly provide add/delete functionality, when that functionality may or may not exist. Modifications to the data should be done directly via the model - IMHO

Thirdly, there is no `JTable#addRow` method